# Packet loss (mostly)

Tags: networking, router, vlan

I'm experiencing packet loss of every second ping package mostly on a VLAN trunk between a router (Mikrotik RB750Gr3) and a switch (Mikrotik CRS112-8G-4S-IN). The packet loss is on all VLANs on that trunk.
Sometimes the packet loss is gone for minutes or even hours. 
I'm assuming that I do not suffer from congestion or performance problems, bad cabling/hardware/software.
What misconfiguration or other reason could cause this packet loss?

Comment: There has been a recent question on this Web-Site related to packet losses and to the ignorable `ping` loss percents. Try to find it and see where it has eventually led.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for my issue was a stupid copy/paste of an ICMP rate limit into the firewall rules.